# Why does Ubuntu(as well as all the linux distros) hangs while copying?

Tags: kernel, system

I have noticed a lot that all the linux distributions hangs while copying files, why does this happens? Isn't this a bug thats present in the linux for a long time. Do only I happend to be the only person to see this?

Comment: Its your computer. I have never had my system hang wil copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad I'm able to answer this for you, because I suspect your question would confuse most serious ubuntu users who simply don't see it your way, as would I not were it not that I do as much support for Windows users as I do.

There's no easy way to tell you this, but Ubuntu doesn't actually hang.  Instead it merely doesn't waste any CPU cycles stroking the ego of its users the way Windows does.  Instead, Ubuntu puts all of its attention to actually doing the desired copy procedure.

You can speed it up or reduce the impact upon your system by upgrading your RAM.

Comment: But, I have noticed that the copying speed is still slower than that in the windows platform. And why is that?

Comment: Oh that!  That's super easy to explain, because I noticed that back in the 1990s when I first upgraded from DOS to Win3.1.  You see, simply put, WINDOWS IS LYING TO YOU!  No, really.  I'm totally serious!  Windows is at best copying your files into the cache as fast as the progress bar claims (although probably not) but it is not actually recording the data to the destination even remotely as fast.  This is why you lose data (usually permanently) if you pull out your USB flashdrive or SD card just as soon as Windows claims as it is done.

Comment: But, to the normal user it would apparently seem as if the system is suffering from problems...Now,to your previous comment, ubuntu's copying speed gradually slows down.And why is that?

Comment: There could be any number of factors in the slowing of the copy, most likely having to do with the hardware cache on the device in question.  There was a time when traditional rotational hard disk drives had no cache at all, and then as manufacturers became more competitive the did anything they could, first adding only a few kilobytes of cache.  These days a 64mb cache is pretty typical, and while that may not sound terribly large, it does give any sort of transfer a head-start beyond which the speed of the transfer will creep downward.